# Como esperar tudo carregar antes de executar uma função?

Tags: javascript

Como posso atrasar uma função, sendo que os checkboxs são gerados dinamicamente, da forma convencional em javascript, e somente executar depois de toda a página ser renderizada e os outros javascripts serem executados?

Estou tentando usar esse código:

```
var count = 0;
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        count++;
    }else{
        count--;
    }
    $('#count').html( count );
});
```

E esse para mostrar no html:

```
<p><div id="count">0</div></p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

como você está gerando os checkbox de forma dinâmica, você precisa fazer o bind do evento click quando eles forem criados.

No seu caso, a maneira mais facil de se fazer isto é substituir o seguinte trexo de codigo:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () { ... });
```

pelo o seguinte:

```
$(document).on("click", "input:checkbox", function () { ... });
```

desta forma, sempre que um `input:checkbox` for adicionado ao `document` o proprio jQuery fará o bind do evento `click` a este elemento recem criado.

caso todos os inputs pertençam ao mesmo form, aconselho usar `$("form-id")` ao inves de `$(document)`.

Comment: Funcionou, vlw cara!!!

Answer (score 0):

tente utilizar a função done após o evento de click:

```
var count;
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        count++;
    }else{
        count--;
    }       
}).done(function(){ 
    $('#count').html( count );
});
```

Comment: Infelizmente o a sua ajuda retornou isso. `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).click(...).done is not a function`.

Obrigado por tentar ajudar!